# Fixing broken Eclipse Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

after updating some plugins my Eclipse Indigo stopped working properly in Ubuntu 12.04.
Now I no longer can create C++ projects or open cpp files (due to some error in org.eclipse.cdt).

I have tried to run a `sudo apt-get purge eclipse*` and reinstall it using `sudo apt-get install eclipse-cdt`, but that didn't solve the issue.

Is there a way I can completely clean eclipse and reinstall it?

Comment: with out knowing whats the error , we can't help you much . please improve your Question with more information .

Comment: Why not install it from the [Eclipse Downloads Page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=linux)?

Comment: I have to agree with Evandro. Dowloading it manually is the better choice. You mostly get a newer version that way and somehow it runs more reliable. You can extract it anywhere you like. I use `/opt/eclipse`. The C++ development tools can be installed afterwards using the eclipse marketplace or you use the C/C++ package right away.

Comment: I don't post comments about the error, because I don't want to fix the error, I simply would like a clean install.
Evandro and Stoneds I heard it is hard to set the compilers downloading it manually, is that true? Or it is as simple as downloading it?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to clean the workspace. Try to rename you eclipse's workspace folder and start eclipse. It should ask you for workspace location before loading any plugins.

Comment: There's usually a lot of important (or at least time-consuming) customization in your workspace, so this solution has that as a drawback.